# How can I open .obj files in blender?

Tags: blender

Each time I try to open a wavefront obj file I get an unsupported file type error. Why is this? Isn't .obj a 3D standard?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: this isnt a programming question and there are many online forums for user questions.

Comment: http://blenderartists.org/

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use import instead of the open menu item.

Menus: File->import->Wavefront (obj)